# Jquery toggleclass function only works on homepage

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, toggleclass

I have a menu that has a drop down sub menu that is hidden until the user clicks on the title.

The menu is part of the MasterPage.master so it appears at the top of each webpage in the website. On the homepage, I can click on the menu title and the sub menu drops down and I can click on the link. It then goes to a page listing departments but when I click on the menu title (on the departments page ie second page) the sub menu does not drop down.

I have tried to narrow down the problem, I thought it was something to do with the CSS on the second page such as the div was fixed but I have removed all content from the second page and the sub-menu still doesn't drop down.

The code below is for one of three menus on MasterPage.master, one of the menus does work on the next page following the user clicking on the title but I do not why one works on the menu below doesn't work.

**Please can you tell me why the code below only works once from the homepage? I have been trying to narrow down the issue for weeks without success.**

**JQuery in MasterPage.master page**

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/jscript"></script>

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.parent').click(function() {
            $('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Menu (DepartmentList.ascx)**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="parent">Brands</HeaderTemplate> 
<ItemTemplate>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="DepartmentRoute" runat="server" 
     NavigateUrl='<%#: GetRouteUrl("DepartmentRoute", new { departmentId = 
 Eval("departmentId"), BrandName = (Eval("Name").ToString().FixUrl())})%>'   
text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CssClass='<%# Eval("DepartmentId").ToString() ==   
Request.QueryString["DepartmentId"] ? "DepartmentSelected" :    
"DepartmentUnselected" %>'></asp:HyperLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ItemTemplate>   
<FooterTemplate>
   </li>
 </ul>
</FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

**CSS Code**

```
#nav {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}

#nav li.parent {
width: 100%;
list-style-type: none;
background-color: #333030;
color: #ffffff;

}

#nav ul.sub-nav a:hover { /*list of departments*/
font-size: 0.8em;
font-family: Verdana;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000;

}
#nav ul.sub-nav a {
font-size: 0.8em;
font-family: Verdana;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}

#nav ul.sub-nav {
display: none;
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#nav ul.visible {
display: block;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0 0 5px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 0.8em;
background-color: #d3c4c4;
border-bottom: solid 2px;
border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}
```

I have copied the code from the page (Catalog3.aspx) that the department menu goes to from the homepage. The DepartmentList menu does not expand to show the sub menu on this page (Catalog3.aspx).

```
 <%@ Page Title="lingerie-luxury" Language="C#"     
MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="Catalog3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Catalog3" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/ProductList.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" 
TagName="ProductList"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpMainContent"   
Runat="Server">
<p class="productTitle"><asp:Label ID="departmentTitle" runat="server"    
Text=""></asp:Label></p>
<div class="DanTest">
<br />
<br />
<h1 class="productTitle">TESTING </h1>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Is there someone that can explain why the menu does not expand on Catalog3.aspx when you click on the menu title? Any suggestions would be greatly received.

Comment: Do you also load all your scripts on that other page. jQuery too?

Comment: The Jquery code above is only in the MasterPage.master but all pages within the website refer to the master file.

Do you know why the jquery code would work on some pages but not others?

Comment: Do you get any js errors on the page? Have you inspected the menu itself to see if the visible class is toggled or not?

Comment: I don't get any Jquery errors when the homepage loads or when I navigate to Catalog3.aspx after clicking on the sub-menu item. How to do you inspect the menu to see if the visible class is toggled? Do you run the debug?

Comment: Is there a different approach I can use to achieve the same result?